# Como fazer WHERE com um nome incompleto para achar o registro que no banco está com o nome completo?

Tags: sql, select, where

Olá,
Preciso fazer o sistema mandar email para a pessoa cadastrada em um formulário como engenheiro encarregado. Aí eu preciso fazer um SQL que busque o email a partir do nome. Até aí ok. Se a pessoa digitar exatamente o nome da pessoa como está no banco, tudo certo. Porém o campo é um input normal, não um *suggest*, não existe nenhuma verificação se o nome digitado realmente existe. Então eu queria que na *query*, se o usuário cadastrasse "João Silva" no formulário, a busca SQL encontrasse no banco o registro "João Guilherme da Silva". Do jeito que está agora, se o usuário digitar apenas "Silva", ele acha "João Guilherme da Silva", mas se digitar "João Silva", ele não encontra nada. Podem me ajudar, por favor?

```
    SELECT user_seq, user_name, user_email, user_elogin 
    FROM tabela_usuarios
    WHERE user_name LIKE < cfqueryparam 
    cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" 
    value="%#arguments.engineerName#%"
```

Obs, uso coldfusion :)

Comment: Importante você `EDITAR` esta pergunta, explicando-a de forma clara, objetiva e direta, enfatizando a dificuldade encontrada. Além disso, nos forneça um [Exemplo mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) do problema, junto com sua tentativa de resolução. E mais, sugiro a leitura do [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%C3%AAncia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%C3%AAs) para entender melhor o funcionamento da plataforma, evitando maiores frustrações.

Comment: Tem certeza que você não consegue buscar pelo id? Se você usar o LIKE ele pode trazer nenhum ou mais de um resultado. Levando em consideração que você precisa enviar o e-mail para o usuário existente, para quem você mandaria? Para todos? Seu código teria uma inconsistência, pois poderia mandar um e-mail para o usuário incorreto.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução é no "form" separar o nome inputado em um array
com vários nomes
por exemplo

FULANO BELTRANO DE TAL

array {FULANO,BELTRANO,TAL}

elimine o DE

faça um sql dinamico com o array

```
(NOME LIKE '%FULANO%BELTRANO%TAL%')
```

Supondo a ordem
OU

```
( (NOME LIKE '%FULANO%') OR
  (NOME LIKE '%BELTRANO%') OR
  (NOME LIKE '%TAL%') )
```

sem levar em conta a ordem

Detalhes da implementação dependem do SGBD e Front-End usados , aqui só a ideia geral.

Obs : Cuidado com [SQL Injection](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

Answer (score -1):

tente:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `name` LIKE '%ped%';
```

use as `%` no inicio e no fim do texto pesquisado.

Comment: Ao pensar em responder uma determinada pergunta, leia [Como escrever uma boa resposta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Além disso, utilize bons argumentos de modo objetivo demonstrando cordialidade.